# Why aren't pointer types subtypes of object?

Tags: c#, pointers, subtyping

```
csharp> int x = 42;
csharp> fixed (int* p = &x) {
      >     object o = p;
      > }
(2,16): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `int*' to `object'
csharp> typeof(int*).BaseType
null
```

Why did the language designers choose for pointer types to not be subtypes of `object` (unlike reference types and value types)? Is there a way to box pointers without using `IntPtr`, `UIntPtr` or a custom class?

Comment: (1) Because language designers did not want us to get too comfortable with pointers. (2) Not as far as I know. What's wrong with `IntPtr`?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight `IntPtr` loses type information.

Comment: If it were possible to wrap pointers in an object, wouldn't conversion back to a typed pointer need an explicit cast anyway? The only difference is that with `IntPtr` the cast back will succeed for pointers of wrong type, while imaginary "unwrap" from an object would throw an exception. Is this the safety issue that you would like to avoid?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Indeed.

Comment: Because Object is much more than a pointer....

Comment: @TonyHopkinson That's irrelevant; they can be boxed.

Comment: @rightfold. How so, boxing is not subclassing. That would be like saying an int, is a descendant of object. True in some languages, but not in c#. So the answer to your question, is basically because the designers chose to have value types.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson `int` is certainly a subtype of `object`; see `typeof(int).BaseType.BaseType`.

Comment: typeof(int) returns a descendant of type, which is a  descendant of Object, so that does not mean int a descendant of Object.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson uh yes it does. If `D` is a subtype of `B` and `E` is a subtype of `D`, then `E` is a subtype of `B`.

Comment: Missing the point. int v = 14; v.ToString, versus 14.ToString()

Comment: @TonyHopkinson `object x = 14; x.ToString() == 14;` clearly shows that `int` is a subtype of `object`.

Comment: And what does 14.ToString() show?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Both show `"14"`. Why would it be any different? Both have `int` as their dynamic types.